# Single Word Request - What do you call a person who can drink a lot?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word for someone who CAN drink a lot? He is not necessarily an alcoholic, but when he drinks, he can drink everyone under the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the words that come to mind are archaic, which I don't think it what you're looking for. Interestingly, in Benjamin Franklin's time, you could have said someone was "biggy," which I could see coming back into use. Other things you could call your drinker would be soak or toper. I can't think of any modern word that doesn't also mean alcoholic, however.
Here's Franklin's list of related words: https://founders.archives.gov/documents/Franklin/01-02-02-0029

Answer (score 1):

People, who can't hold their alcohol well, are called [lightweight](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=lightweight).

The antonym and the word, which you are looking for, is a [heavyweight](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=heavyweight).

Obviously, these two words are slang and not very formal.

Comment: You would need to use this strictly in context, since heavyweight is also used in some sports.

Comment: There's 'hard drinker' too.